# Alternatives to Diagnostics.Process to run a simple shell command!

Tags: c#

I need to run a simple application with c# is there anyway, and I mean anyway other than Diagnostics.Process to run a simple shell command?

Comment: What's wrong with `Process.Start`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Even if you use a class that does this for you, it will use System.Diagnostics.Process internally.  You could use P/Invoke, but that is the OPPOSITE direction as far as simplicity.  Using System.Diagnostics.Process is by far the easiest way to do this.